User's size font affect only one Column in a HTML table
I create a table direct in html (no bootstrap nor similar), but when I see this on my android phone, one column has a very big size font. It seems to be related with a cell with a long text. I tried everything to reduce the size of the font of this column, without success. The size of the font of the column, has to be the same as the others columns, even if there is one or more cells are long string.
HTML:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Trouble</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon"  type="image/x-icon" href="Objetos\MyIcon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyCSSFile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" ><tbody align="center">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#BFBFBF" style="border: 1px solid"><font color=\"#000000\"><b>Date</b></th>
                <th bgcolor="#BFBFBF" style="border: 1px solid"><font color=\"#000000\"><b>DataType A</b></th>
                <th bgcolor="#BFBFBF" style="border: 1px solid"><font color=\"#000000\"><b>DataType B</b></th>
                <th bgcolor="#BFBFBF" style="border: 1px solid"><font color=\"#000000\"><b>DataType C</b></th>
                <th bgcolor="#BFBFBF" style="border: 1px solid"><font color=\"#000000\"><b>DataType D</b></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>    NA    </td>
                <td>Data 1A</td>
                <td>Data 1B</td>
                <td>Data 1C</td>
                <td>Data 1D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14-06-2024</td>
                <td>Data 2A</td>
                <td>Data 2B</td>
                <td>Data 2C</td>
                <td>Data 2D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17-06-2024</td>
                <td>Data 3A</td>
                <td>Data 3B</td>
                <td>Data 3C<br>Long string. This String needs to be long.<br> More than 255 character. With this string all the table is <br> affected. Without this string, the table works as suppose<br> to work with. I don't know why this happens.<br>In this case, if I remove from here to the end, works fine.</td>
                <td>Data 3D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>01-08-2024</td>
                <td>Data 4A</td>
                <td>Data 4B</td>
                <td>Data 4C</td>
                <td>Data 4D</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

CSS:
th, td {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Open Sans,Arial;
}

Only the row DataType C is bigger.
I tried with div, I tried with several media (all, screen, handheld). Nothing works. The table looks uneven. My Phone is configured with a very big user-size-font. Then I realize that only this column is affected by the phone user font size configuration.
